# Problem with Sortables in Scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous, typeerror

I'm having a problem with getting my divs to become sortable using Scriptaculous's Drag and Drop Library.

```
<pre id="leftcol">
<div id="id0"><h3>Date and Time</h3><div class="moduleContent"></div></div>
<div id="id14"><h3>Calculator</h3><div class="moduleContent"></div></div>
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
Sortable.create("leftcol", {tag:$$('div'), treeTag:$$('pre')});
</script>
```

When I try to debug with Safari's Web Inspector, I get the following error:
    `TypeError: Result of expression 'tagName.toUpperCase' [undefined] is not a function. dragdrop.js:932`

Is the problem in the dragdrop.js file or is it in my code, and if it's in my code, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Sortable.create`](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/sortable-create) method expects that the options `tag` and `tagTree` are simply two strings, not a set of DOM elements:

```
Sortable.create("leftcol", {tag:'div', treeTag:'pre'});
```

Try it out [here](http://jsbin.com/awiso/).